# Places to avoid in Fallout 3 as a beginner

Tags: fallout-3

I got Fallout 3 for Christmas and I have found Megaton and TenPenny Tower. I noticed that with the weapons I have I am always searching for ammo and dying a lot. So are the any places I should avoid until I'm a higher level, also, are there any types of weapons I should have handy on a moment's notice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're just starting out, I suggest following the main quest until you reach a city (like Megaton) and then explore that city for side quests.

Generally, the game will take you to places that you can handle, and then give you quests you can handle while you're there.  If you do all/most of the sidequests, you'll level up enough to be ready for the next plot mission.

Once you have a few levels under your belt, you'll be better able to handle yourself against the random encounters of the wasteland, and you can do a bit more exploring.

While traveling in the wasteland, save before you leave a safe location, and then save often (ideally in a different slot than your "safe" save).  This is overly paranoid - the game's not THAT unforgiving, but if you want to avoid the frustration of dying constantly, it helps.

That said, here are some general tips for the early game:

- Try to avoid downtown DC, since there are Super Mutants there.  When the plot takes you there, it will also give you some help, so don't worry too much.
- While out and about, you may encounter groups of raiders.  Big groups of raiders can cause trouble from range, so try to keep them around a corner and take them out one at a time.
- If you have the DLC, Operation: Anchorage is pretty easy, but the rest are somewhat challenging at low levels.
- Deathclaws are bad news - run if you see one.

Weapon-wise, it depends on what your character has points in.  Pistols are easy to find and the ammo is plentiful in the early game.  Rifles can do more damage and at a longer range.  Energy weapons and big guns I usually leave for the mid to late game, but they can do a lot of damage against targets that would normally shrug off small arms fire.

Comment: What are deathclaws and when am I able to take them on?

Comment: @Jonco98, Deathclaws are enormous animals that stand up on their rear feet and swipe huge claws at you.  They look a little like enormous demons.  As far as taking them on...  when nothing in the wasteland poses a threat to you, you're ready to fight a deathclaw.

Comment: @Jonco98 [Be afraid... be *very* afraid](http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110511012723/fallout/images/thumb/e/e6/Enclave_deathclaw.png/500px-Enclave_deathclaw.png)

Comment: It's also worth noting that you can find unique versions of regular weapons (or even just unique weapons) which are generally better then the average weapon. Trekking over to Republic of Dave is a pain, but it's worth it just for *Ol' Painless* IMO.